# Trying to create a field that calculates the total count of items in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I have reviewed all of the questions that are similar to mine but none have the answer I'm looking for.

Ultimately, I am attempting to create a dashboard. I have a Helpdesk which accepts Support Requests from the customer. I need to display the total New requests, In Progress requests, Waiting on Customer Response requests, and Completed Requests.

I don't need someone to tell me how to get that built as I know this is not the forum for that. I am looking for an answer to how to get a number from the different statuses I mentioned above. Please help with something as simple as a link to a possible solution or something more detailed.

I do not have access to the servers by the way so it will need to be a calculated column or some sort of OTB solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One, no code, way is to create a Classic UI View with the Group By option and group by Status.

[image]

If you would like to do some JavaScript work in a SharePoint Page or Content Editor Web Part, you can use a REST call to get counts on list items.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I don't really do a whole lot of coding and have never done a REST call. Can you tell me where I can get information about manipulating SP data with code such as REST calls? Maybe a book or a site? Seems like there is only specific answers to specific questions on the web and that's only found on these sorts of forums.

Comment: There's a video and lots of links here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx   If you want to experiment with examples, I've put together a "REST tester" that you can add to a Content Editor Web Part in your own SP site. http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2017/04/a-sharepoint-rest-api-tester-with-ajax.html